# Why did Truth try to activate the Halo array?

Tags: halo

The Prophet of Truth is depicted as a highly religious individual. During Halo 2 he captured 343 Guilty Spark, who told him how to activate the Halo rings. But I have no doubt that Spark would also have told him what they actually do. Truth would have seen him as a representative of their gods, and must have listened; failing that, he could have picked up on a million other clues that would have told him Halo's true purpose. Yet he still continues to try to activate the rings, surely knowing he would die.

Is there anything that indicates if he knew that, and if so, why he continued with his suicidal campaign?

Comment: alot of charismatic religious leaders found religious suicide cults. or he wants to bring all his people to his gods at once, aka through an extinction event.

Answer (score 3):

Mm, you have to remember that there were some rather important bits cut from the story of the game, for whatever reason. For example, we see in the end, the Brute trying to force Captain Keane to insert the Codex, which doesn't make any sense *unless they knew by that point that Humans were the ancients they worshipped*.

Yea, he probably knew exactly what would happen when he set off the Halo system. And he didn't care. Because he also believed that the Ancients had lets the Halo system as a passageway to...a better place.

But that said, don't assume that he wouldn't have filtered what he learned through his own preconceptions. Remember what happened with Gravemind, when the Prophet and the Oracle were arguing? The exact words were "There are none so worthless as these Oracles! They know nothing of the Great Journey!" "And you know nothing about containment! You have demonstrated complete disregard for even the most basic protocols!" (Thanks PointlessSpike for correcting my memory)

Comment: The *exact* words were "There are none so worthless as these Oracles! They know nothing of the Great Journey!" "And you know nothing about containment! You have demonstrated complete disregard for even the most basic protocols!" I have memorised the script of Halo 2 through excessive numbers of playthroughs.

Comment: Truth already knew that humans were known as "Reclaimers" at the start of the war- this was shown in *Contact Harvest*. Spark would have told him that humans were needed to start the process, and they were already aware that humans were able to easily use Forerunner tech (that was in Halo Wars).

Answer (score 0):

Spark neglected to tell Master Chief what Halo did in CE, believing Chief already knew the specifics of the ring. It's not out of the question that Spark believed the same of Truth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a valid frame challenge to the first part of the question, but what about the part that suggests Truth could have figured it out on his own? "...he could have picked up on a million other clues that would have told him Halo's true purpose"